# Use translation in ng-template as parameter for a component

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to use a translation as a property on one of my components:

```
<some-component route="/foo" label="foo" /><!-- foo should be translated -->
<some-component route="/bar" label="bar" /><!-- bar should be translated -->
```

I have two routes in my component:

```
menuRoutes = ['/foo', '/bar']
```

Now to use these routes in the template I have started with:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let menuRoute of menuRoutes">
  <some-component route="{{ menuRoute }}" label="{{ menuRoute }}" />
</ng-container>
```

How can I pass translations defined in a template as a property to `some-component`?

Started with the following setup which allows me to statically render the translations. But I'm not able to use the translation as a property on some-component.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let menuRoute of menuRoutes">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="translations; context:{ $implicit: menuItem }">
    <!-- this would statically render the translation --> 
    <!-- <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="translations; context:{ $implicit: menuItem }"></ng-template> -->
    <!-- But I would like to use it in the label property of the some-component -->
    <some-component route="{{ menuRoute }}" label="???" />
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #translations let-menuItem>
  <ng-container[ngSwitch]="menuRoutes">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'/foo'">
      <span i18n="@@foo">Foo</span>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'/bar'">
      <span i18n="@@bar">Bar</span>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a template ref variable (`#translations` in the question description) in the same component is not possible.

The trick is to use a *different component* and define the component *"some-component"* there with the translation.

## Step 1: Define different module

**./different.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  // include the custom component here
  imports: [CommonModule, CustomComponentModule],
})
export class DifferentModule {}
```

**./different.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'different-component',
  templateUrl: './different.component.html'
})
export class DifferentComponent {
  @Input() menuRoute: string;
}
```

**./new.component.html**

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="menuRoute">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'/foo'">
    <!-- you can use a prefix of i18-* to the property you like to translate -->
    <some-component i18n-label="@@foo" label="Foo"></custom-component>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'/bar'">
    <!-- you can use a prefix of i18-* to the property you like to translate -->
    <some-component i18n-label="@@bar" label="Bar"></custom-component>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

## Step 2: use it in your component

**./app.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let menuRoute of menuRoutes">
  <different-component [menuRoute]="menuRoute"></different-component>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is correct - if you look at your code you are trying to send an 18!n translation into the component from the parent - you stated that you wanted to pass the data from the parent and were not sure how to get the translation to the child - the op answered you with input bindings because one can use them dynamically.

the translation in the route label is called by handlebars - {{ }} but you should not be passing the data in this way - or by the variable directly.

an input binding in the child component the one receiving the label should be done with a directive binding to the input - []=""

the variable is set in the parent.

```xml
<ng-container *ngFor="let menuRoute of menuRoutes">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="translations; context:{ $implicit: menuItem }">
    <!-- how to use the result of the translation in the label parameter? -->
    <some-component [route]="menuRoute?.YOUR ROUTE VARIABLE" [label]="menuRoute?.YOUR VARIABLE" />
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #translations let-menuItem>
  <ng-container[ngSwitch]="menuRoutes">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'/foo'">
      <span i18n="@@foo">Foo</span>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'/bar'">
      <span i18n="@@bar">Bar</span>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

In the child component that you are calling you should import input into angular common and declare the variable after the naming of the component.

If you try to pass a variable without passing it as a directive - it will not function correctly, and will not be properly sanitized by the DOM.